# Torrent client randomly probing internal network when DHT is enabled

Tags: bittorrent, p2p, transmission

I'm using Transmission but looking at some posts on different forums this doesn't seem to be client specific.

When DHT is enabled I can see get_peers requests sent to random internal addresses. These are clearly distinct from local peer discovery - which I keep disabled.

Considering that any peer on the DHT can spoof their IP, I first suspected that someone is trying to scan my network. However without being able to get replies back that would make no sense. Besides, reverse path filtering is enabled so that would make it unlikely.

So is this kind of behavior expected when DHT is enabled?

Comment: I think this is more likely to be misbehaving/badly coded or misconfigured clients.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the result of other peers advertising their internal IP address via DHT. (Possibly those clients are behind CGNATs and think that 10.x.x.x is their "WAN" address because that's what UPnP reports, or possibly they're literally including their internal address for some reason – the latter is likely if you also have PEX enabled.) Because of their nature, it is impossible for your client to distinguish private addresses belonging to other networks from address belonging to yours.